# R mutate won't return function values correctly

Tags: r

I have a function to extract the month from a string of text, matching a particular pattern (like MAR06):

```
library(dplyr)
pattern <- "(JAN|FEB|MAR|APR|MAY|JUN|JUL|AUG|SEP|OCT|NOV|DEC)\\d{2,2}"

find_month <- function(x)
{
extracted <- str_extract(x, pattern)
month_string <- substr(extracted, 1, 3)
if(!is.na(month_string) && month_string[[1]] == 'MAY')
{
    value <- 1
}
else
{
    value <- -1
}
return(value)
}
```

To simplify things, I'm only checking here to see if the month is May.
It works fine when I test it manually:

```
> find_month("HELLO THERE MAY06")
[1] 1
> find_month("BYE SEP12")
[1] -1
```

Yet when I call it on a dataframe, it always returns 1 for every row:

```
a = c("HELLO THERE MAY06", "BYE SEP12")
b = c(TRUE, FALSE)
df = data.frame(desc=a, other=b)

df_mutated <- mutate(df, month = find_month(desc))
df_mutated
           desc other month
1 HELLO THERE MAY06  TRUE     1
2         BYE SEP12 FALSE     1
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why not just use `grepl("MAY", "HELLO THERE MAY06", fixed = TRUE)` and convert to numeric if needed?  That will give 1 for yes and 0 for no

Comment: @RichardScriven: maybe `grepl('MAY\\d{2}', ...)` to prevent matches on, e.g., `"MAYBE NOV07"`.

Answer (score 1):

To answer "what am I doing wrong", you can look at what happens when you `debugonce(find_month)`. The `mutate` function is vectorised, so `extracted` will be a vector of matches, and `month_string` will be a vector of month names. Since `&&` returns a length-one vector, your code then returns `1` or `-1` depending on whether there are any NAs and whether the first element of `month_string` is `'MAY'` (since you use `month_string[[1]]`).

You can vectorise your mutate function by replacing your `if` with `ifelse`:

```
find_month <- function(x) {
  extracted <- str_extract(x, pattern)
  month_string <- substr(extracted, 1, 3)
  ifelse(!is.na(month_string) & month_string == 'MAY', 1, -1)
}
```

That said, Richard's [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38277618/r-mutate-wont-return-function-values-correctly/38277681#comment63974402_38277618) to use `grepl` is sensible.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `str_detect`

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   mutate(month = c(1, -1)[(str_detect(desc, "MAY")+1)] )
#                desc other month
#1 HELLO THERE MAY06  TRUE    -1
#2         BYE SEP12 FALSE     1
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have distinct names in the `desc` column, you can just use `rowwise()` to apply your non-vectorized function to each row:

```
R> df_mutated2 <- df %>% group_by(desc) %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(month = find_month(desc))
R> df_mutated2
Source: local data frame [2 x 3]
Groups: <by row>

               desc other month
              (chr) (lgl) (dbl)
1 HELLO THERE MAY06  TRUE     1
2         BYE SEP12 FALSE    -1
```